# How can I place a header image fixed at the top of my Tab Application?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to create a Tab Application with a header image that is always present, no matter what Tab Item is active.

The example would be Foursquare:

[image]

I want to be able to place buttons and have different information displayed on that header.

Is that a simple Navigation Bar or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the easiest thing to do is to write:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:
     [UIImage imageNamed:@"UINavigationBar.png"] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
}
```

At my MainViewController, and all Navigation bars that get created on each view controller gets configured like that.

Answer (score 3):

Usually, for each tab is associated a viewController. You can notice it in the boilerplate which xcode creates when you choose "Tabbed Application".
Then, in each `viewDidLoad` or in the `init` of each viewcontroller you can set:

```
self.navigationItem.titleView=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

Then just change `self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem` and `self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem` with your controls on each viewController.

**Edit**:

In the appDelegate (in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method) you've to set something like this if you want use the navigationcontrollers:

```
 UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
 UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];
 UINavigationController *myNav1=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController1];
 UINavigationController *myNav2=[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:viewController2];
 UIImage *navBackgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_navBar.png"];
 UIImage *tabBackgroundImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"bg_tabBar.png"];
 [myNav1.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];//iOS 5 only
 [myNav2.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:navBackgroundImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];//iOS 5 only
 [[UITabBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:tabBackgroundImg];//iOS 5 only
 self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:myNav1, myNav2, nil];
 self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Comment: That didn't work... Maybe I'm doing something wrong... But when I create a Tabbed application, there is no Navigation Bar on it. Should I just drag a Navigation Bar to a specific tab view?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a simple navigation bar, but they aren't exactly simple. You need to place/create a NavigationItem on the bar (after placing/creating the bar itself) and then set the titleView to a custom view with your image. According to the documentation the left bar button (close in your first screen) has to be nil or else the titleView is ignored. Though you can place buttons in this custom view for left buttons.